# How to write a query that returns rows that do not have a specific value in a dynamic list of future dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a problem trying to accurately identify customers that have left a business service permanently. Currently, there is an incorrect definition of these customers defined as 'churners' in operation within the business.

'Churners' may re-enter the platform in the following months, and I don't want to include those specific accounts in my result set.

These accounts appear similar to the following table:

| ID | Month_End_Date | Activity_Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 31/07/22 | Customer |
| 123 | 30/06/22 | Customer |
| 123 | 31/05/22 | Customer |
| 123 | 30/04/22 | Customer |
| 123 | 31/03/22 | Customer |
| 123 | 28/02/22 | Order |
| 123 | 31/01/22 | Churn |

Whereas an actual 'churner' should appear as the following:

| ID | Month_End_Date | Activity_Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | 31/07/22 | x |
| 321 | 30/06/22 | x |
| 321 | 31/05/22 | x |
| 321 | 30/04/22 | x |
| 321 | 31/03/22 | x |
| 321 | 28/02/22 | x |
| 321 | 31/01/22 | Churn |

And in some cases, these customers DO NOT populate any further rows (unique by Month_End_Date) within the dataset:

| ID | Month_End_Date | Activity_Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | 31/01/22 | Churn |

So my question is, how can I write an SQL query that will show me the accounts that meet the parameter of Activity_Flag = 'Churn' and DO NOT HAVE any further Activity_Flags within the table itself?

Hope this is enough information,

I have tried to filter these applicable customers within the dataset by understanding unique monthly churners and their following behaviour (activity_type) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Row_Number` function with the `Partition By` clause and Order by `Month_End_Date` descending to get only records where the last record for the given `ID` has an   `Activity_Flag` of `Churn`:

```
select x.ID
from
(
    select ID, Activity_Flag, 
    Row_Number() Over (Partition By ID 
    Order By Month_End_Date desc) as rn
    from yourtable
) x
where x.rn = 1 and x.Activity_Flag = 'Churn'
```

Comment: Can you think of any reason as to why this query returns a different result set each time it's run? I've run the above both for all month_end_date(s) within my table, as well as specific month_end_dates, and the result set seems to change slightly each query. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @ctjanalytics If more records are coming into the database then the result sets are going to possibly be different, I have no idea what the traffic looks like on your backend. As for running this on specific months, then it would only return the results for that month, which I would wager is going to be different than running it for the entire table. Providing some sample data or better yet, a sql-fiddle would help a lot.